# ELK: Merge multiple events into one

Tags: logstash, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

My system logs requests.

If and when a response arrives, I want to have it logged with the request object.

Meaning, when I query ElasticSearch for activity, I'll get a row for each request, either containing a response or not. This is similar to an SQL LEFT OUTER JOIN.

I am open to solutions everywhere along the Logstash-ElasticSearch pipeline. However, since this is time-series data, aggregation buckets are not a possible solution since they prevent paging.

Thanks.

Comment: What "system" is logging?  Can you provide a sample of your logs?

Comment: Proprietary system that logs HTTP activity, let's assume there is a request ID field that can connect the request and response.

Comment: If the request document has your ID field, and the response document has the ID field, then you can query where myIdField="myIdValue" to get them both (or only one if the response is not found).  Assuming you want more, can you perhaps provide an example?

Comment: I want to query for all requests during the last X minutes and get their rows to contain their responses as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to store the request with the response every time you log them. You can also have scripted queries in Elasticsearch - complicated solution but can work.